# django-allatuh login automatic on "/"

Tags: python, django, microsoft-graph-api, django-allauth

I have a program in DJango. I have a second program called "users". Inside I have implemented login and login with microsoft authentication. I have done this using the "allauth" library. Now I want you when accessing the page, (without having to access the "/login" page) check if you have a microsoft account. That is, when I enter the main page: "/", it takes me to the page to choose a microsoft account in the event that it has one. Without having to press any buttons. That's possible? That it automatically connects if I am connected to a Microsoft account.

This is my view:

```
def home(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = authenticate(request, auth_entry='microsoft')
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('main_page')
    else:
        microsoft_account = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=request.user, provider='microsoft')
        if microsoft_account.exists():
            return redirect('main_page')
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

As you can see, the problem is that I firt see if the user is authenticated. But if it the first time the user enters, it is imposible to be autheticated. I don't know if I explained myself correctly, I want the Microsoft authentication to be automatic

Answer (score -1):

```
def home(request):
    user = authenticate(request, auth_entry='microsoft')
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('main_page')
    
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.